# Embed a dynamically generated Qt chart, manipulated and created in c ++, into a QML layaut

Tags: qt, qml, qtcharts

I´m new in programming Qt withe QML, and I Like to do an program which is designed in QML and has one frond-end compounded, the QtChart, which is crated in c++.

I like to show different styles and typs of the chart in one specific location in the QML frond-end, so i think it wood be easier to do all the Chart manipulation in c++.

Pleas help me, and tell me if I`m doing wrong way?
And if there is any way pleas show me.

Thanks in advance.

My Idea:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine,QUrl::fromLocalFile("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject *object = component.create();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine2;
    engine2.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *objekt = engine2.rootObjects().first();

    QObject *rect = objekt->findChild<QObject*>("myChart");
    if (rect)
    {
        qDebug("it works");

        QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
        series->append(0, 6);
        series->append(2, 4);
        series->append(3, 8);
        series->append(7, 4);
        series->append(10, 5);

        QChart *graph = new QChart();
        graph->addSeries(series);
        QChartView *mayChart = new QChartView(graph);
        mayChart->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

        //Hear I don´t know, how I can do such an operation 
        rect.setCentralWidget(mayChart);

     }
}
```

QML "main.qml"

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    objectName: "mainWindow"

    Rectangle{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "black"
        objectName: "rect"

    }
 }
```

Comment: Where did you define `myChart` ? And in QML, I recommend using [ChartView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#details) with the different styles defined [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmlmodule.html), define your look there, and use Qt's signal/slot system to exchange data in C++.

Comment: Thanks for your response 

Ohh I´m sorry, I mixed to Programs.
 ("myChart") - > is normally named ("rect"); as the objectName: "rect"

And withe styles i mean, I want create a chart withe 1 LineSeries or up to 10, ore change some to an Bars

Comment: [LineSeries](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-lineseries.html) and [HorizontalBarSeries](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-horizontalbarseries.html) can be directly declared in QML. Using [Repeater](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) allows you to generate as many of them as you want

Answer (score 2):

`QChart` and `QChartView` are `QtWidget` based classes, you can't use those with `QtQuick2`.

You will need a `QtQuick2` `ChartView` element and communicate the data between C++ and QML.

One option for that would be to create an empty `LineSeries` in QML and pass it to C++ fpr filling.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.

but one question to you method, can you show more then one LineSeries?
an may, can you show me an Example?

Comment: It should also be possible to create multiple LineSeries, `ChartView´ as a `createSeries` method. I've unfortunately no example code handy and I am not sure if I can find time to develop one. Would make a nice addition to the Qt documentation though